# Setup Thread Group doesn't run in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to run the JMeter test plan in the GitLab pipeline and facing a strange issue that Setup Thread Group doesn't run when the test plan is triggered.

JMeter Version : 5.4.1
Java : Open JDK 11
System : Linux

The test plan starts running all the other thread groups without running the Setup Thread Group first causing the test to fail completely. I am running JMeter in non gui mode.

Tried disabling all other thread group and still the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 reasons for not running the Thread Group, no matter whether it [setUp](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group), [tearDown](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group), [normal](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) or [custom](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/#Thread-Groups):

1. The number of threads is `0`
2. The Thread Group has [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) and the CSV file is not present
3. The Thread Group has a [JMeter Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) and the plugin is not installed

Normally JMeter reports the fact of starting and stopping threads in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), you can take a look there and see what's going on. Additionally you can [increase JMeter's logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) to DEBUG level if normal level doesn't show the root cause of the unexpected behaviour.

And last but not the least [according to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.5](https://lists.apache.org/thread/k575c2oqnr0pv52fckcg399o4nkqt8c6) (or whatever is the latest stable version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page)